# Categorizing Sales by Team

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question is: "In one record for each squad, show the team, its US (area = ‘-US’) sales for 2018 and its UK (area = ‘UK’) sales for 2018. "

Would this not work?

```
SELECT squad, SUM(CASE WHEN area = “US” THEN sales_2018 ELSE 0 END) AS “US”, SUM(CASE WHEN area = “UK” then sales_2018 ELSE 0 END) AS “UK”
FROM squad A
Inner join Sales b on a.account = b.account
GROUP BY squad
```

Tables involved:

[image]

Comment: `“US”` Technically no, since this type of quotation mark is not valid in TSQL and because double quotes are not used to delimit string constants. But rather than ask, why don't you actually execute the query using your database and evaluate the result?

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you can use pivot to achieve your result.

```
select squad,[US],[UK] from(
select sq.squad,sq.Area,sa.sales_2018 from Sales sa inner join Squad sq on sa.account=sq.account
) tbl
pivot(
sum(sales_2018) for Area in ([US],[UK])
) pvtTable
```

The result of inner query returns

| squad | Area | sales_2018 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IT | US | 1300.00 |
| IT | UK | 3300.00 |
| Finance | US | 3400.00 |
| Finance | UK | 2500.00 |

After applying Pivot

| squad | US | UK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IT | 3400.00 | 2500.00 |
| Finance | 1300.00 | 3300.00 |